How to Keep a radio button checked after form submission
Here is my problem: I have radio buttons in a loop, in a form (in spring boot) and I would like the radio button that was checked to remain checked after submitting the form and especially when we return to the choice page , just to not be able to recheck the same choice (in JS). Basically, I make a choice, I submit => it sends me to another page but when I return to my page of choice, the previous choice must be disabled.
Form:
<form action="#" th:action="@{/piece}" modelAttribute="piece"  method="post"
     id="formP" onsubmit="">
        <tr th:each="piece: ${pieces}">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="${piece.nom}" th:value="'Valider : '+ ${piece.nom}"
             onclick="saveform()"  />
            <label class="radio-image">
                <input type="radio" name="img" th:value="${piece.img}" onclick="check()"  required>
                <img th:src="@{${'/images/'+ piece.img}}" />
            </label>
            <br>
        </tr>
    </form>

Function to retrieve the choice in localStorage:
function check() {
    
    var btnPieceRad = document.getElementsByName('img');
    for (i = 0; i < btnPieceRad.length; i++) {
        if ((btnPieceRad[i].checked)) {
            var valeur = btnPieceRad[i].value;
            localStorage.setItem("radPiece", valeur);
        }
    }
}

I try:
function saveform() {
    var radPiece = localStorage.getItem("radPiece") ;
    radPiece.getElementsByTagName('radio')[radPiece].disabled = true;   
}

Without result
Then I got inspired by the subject How do I disable and check which option that I chose in the radio buttons after form submission?
And I do :
function saveform() {
    var formPiece = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    formPiece.addEventListener("submit",function(){
        var inputs = formPiece[0].getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
            var this_input = inputs[i];
            if( this_input.type=="radio") {
            this_input.disabled = true;
          
        }
        }
    });
}

Without result and I have a sneaky error in the console:Uncaught on this line:
formPiece.addEventListener("submit",function()
Thanks for your help

a sneaky error ... "Uncaught on this line" isn't an error any browser ever outputs - please add the EXACT error - note: you'll probably want to prevent the default submit behaviour of a form, since that is probably what is happening

The title mentions "checked" but the body mentions "disabled". What is the actual goal?

Your getElementsByTagName('radio') call results in nothing (I'm guessing). Is there any element in the DOM with the tag name <radio>? I know there's the <input type='radio'>.

Also, I think you should use something like <input type='radio' onchange='updateRadioData(this)' ...> and make the updateRadioData function save that specific field passed as first parameter in the storage or do anything else that you want with it.

Did you not ask the exact same question a few days ago?

Note you cannot use the same name for the radios, since only ONE can be checked. Also it is not recommended to use a radio to check or uncheck, since once you check one, you cannot revert to all unchecked except using a script
Change
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="${piece.nom}" th:value="'Valider : '+ ${piece.nom}" onclick="saveform()"  />` 

to
<input type="submit" value="${piece.nom}" th:value="'Valider : '+ ${piece.nom}" />


and
<input type="radio" name="img" th:value="${piece.img}" onclick="check()"  required>

to
<input type="checkbox" name="img" th:value="${piece.img}" required>

Then you delegate - NOTE: this assumes the number of checkboxes do not change between stored in localStorage and retrieved. So perhaps use sessionStorage instead.
I also assume the value of the checkbox did not change when reloaded. You MAY want to remove the required on the box too
window.addEventListener('load',() => {
  const checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checked') || '[]'); // get the list
  const rads = document.querySelectorAll('#formP input[name=img]');
  checked.forEach((chk,i) => {
    rads[i].checked = rads[i].disabled = chk); // check and disable
  }
  const form = document.getElementById('formP');
  // form.addEventListener('submit',saveForm); // no longer needed
  form.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (!tgt.?name === 'img') return; // not a radio
    rads.forEach((rad,i) => checked[i] = rad.checked; // save the states
    localStorage.setItem('checked',JSON.stringify(checked)); // only place to write
  });
});


thank you for your answers, now I have to manage to check the previous choices and not just the last one

I am not sure I understand. My code should check all. Can you post relevant RENDERED HTML and perhaps consider using a checkbrox instead of radio if you want to check more than one with the same name?

If you use select, you can save the selectedIndex

mplungjan, I changed to checkbox and everything works thank you.

That is great. I already had some misgivings about you using radios. See my updated answer for why. Also please visit this help page
